# Angular rxjs to rxjs 6 and rxrs-compat

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've tried issuing the following command:

```
 npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

but I can't find the `rxjs-compat` folder.  Anyway, here's the real problem:

```
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
 import { startWith, DebounceTime } from 'rxjs/Operator';
 ...
 ngOnInit() {
  this.products$ = this.searchSubject
    .startWith(this.searchTerm)
    .debounceTime(300)
 }
```

I see that startWith.js and debounceTime.js both reference rxjs-compat.  That's why I attempted to install it. I think my 2 import statements are correct but probably not my ngOnInit.

Comment: Does your code not work? You haven't described an actual problem. I'd recommend using e.g. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration for migration.

Comment: Error:  Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'.ts(2339)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are asking for is how to convert that code to use [Pipeable Operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators).

```
import { startWith, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.products$ = this.searchSubject
    .pipe(startWith(this.searchTerm), debounceTime(300));
 }
```

Comment: No, I hadn't considered using .pipe().  Anyway, trying this, the error comes back with "Cannot find name 'debounceTime'.ts".

Comment: See the edit @Dale. You do need to import the operators in your code file.

Comment: I also fixed the broken link to the article @Dale, that should help you better understand the how this works.

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of rxjs compat is to make rxjs v5 syntax work with rxjs v6.  If you're writing new code, should use the new syntax, which requires pipe and importing the operators:

```
import { startWith, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators'

this.products$ = this.searchSubject.pipe(
  startWith(this.searchTerm),
  debounceTime(300)
)
```

however, if you're using the v5 syntax:

```
this.products$ = this.searchSubject
                     .startWith(this.searchTerm)
                     .debounceTime(300)
```

you just need rxjs-compat installed. You don't need to do any other imports besides your Subject, but this will stop working with rxjs v7, so it's in your interest to be migrating asap as v7 is in beta releases right now I believe.

Comment: I like your thinking, but using the v6 code returns the error "Cannot find name 'debounceTime'.ts". – Dale

Comment: You have a typo or a config issue somewhere